# How to load environment specific configuration with requirejs?

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I am making a single page app and using backbone with requirejs. Now I want to include different configurations depending environment variable. I don't know how can I do this and what is best practices.

I have three different config file:

`config.js` : This keep common configurations.

`config.dev.js` : This keeps development environment specific configurations

`config.production.js` : This keeps production specific configurations

I am extending Config model(in config.js) from environment specific model and I requiring the Config model from other modules.
This working fine but downloading dev and production config files both. I want only load config.dev.js or config.production.js not both.

```
// config.js
define([
  'backbone',
  'modules/config/config.dev',
  'modules/config/config.production'
], function(Backbone, DevConfig, ProdConfig) {

    // Select environment model
    EnvConfig = (ENV == 'dev') ? DevConfig : ProdConfig;

    var ConfigModel = EnvConfig.extend({
        // Extending attributes.
        defaults: _.extend({
           foo : 'bar'
        }, EnvConfig.prototype.defaults)

    });

    return new ConfigModel();

});
```

In other modules I am using Config as below style:

```
define([
    'backbone',
    'modules/config/config'
], function(Backbone, Config) {

    var ProfileModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        urlRoot: Config.get('apiRoot') + '/profiles'

        ...
    });

    return ProfileModel;
});
```

How to load one of development or production specific config file, not both?

Comment: So your problem is that it downloads both files?

Comment: Yes. I want download only required. `config.dev.js` or `config.production.js`, not both.

Comment: Perhaps you could find a way to use `require` but as it is async...

Comment: How can I return Config Model with `require`?. I am trying with require but define return undifened from module because async.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure where the `ENV` variable comes from, but assuming it's just a global variable you could do something like this:

**index.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // adding it here so the example works on its own
    window.ENV = 'production'; // or 'dev'
    // this will be added to RequireJS configuration
    var require = {
      paths: {
        // 'env-config' will be an alias for actual file name
        'env-config': 'config.' + window.ENV
      }
    };
</script>
<script data-main="scripts/main" src="scripts/requirejs.js"></script>
```

**config.dev.js:**

```
define({
    'env': 'development!'
});
```

**config.production.js:**

```
define({
    'env': 'production!'
});
```

**main.js:**

```
require(['config', 'env-config'], function(conf, envConfig) {
   console.log('The environment is: ', envConfig.env);
});
```

Comment: I moved the `paths` into `main.js` and it still works so `env.js` just contains `window.ENV = "production";`